# install postgres on centos

Tags: postgresql, centos7

I install postgres in centos7.9
Follow the document steps
https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-install-postgresql-on-centos-7/
Encountered the following issues

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql.service
Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

```
sudo systemctl status postgresql.service
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 14:56:24 CST; 27s ago
  Process: 27102 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=127)

VM-20-7-centos systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
VM-20-7-centos systemd[1]: postgresql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=127
VM-20-7-centos systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
VM-20-7-centos systemd[1]: Unit postgresql.service entered failed state.
VM-20-7-centos systemd[1]: postgresql.service failed.
```

```
sudo journalctl -xe
Mar 13 14:56:24 VM-20-7-centos systemd[1]: Unit postgresql.service entered failed state.
Mar 13 14:56:24 VM-20-7-centos systemd[1]: postgresql.service failed.
Mar 13 14:56:24 VM-20-7-centos polkitd[702]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:27096:45009466 (system bus name :1.1559, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Au
Mar 13 14:56:24 VM-20-7-centos sudo[27095]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 13 14:56:52 VM-20-7-centos sudo[27219]:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status postgresql.service
Mar 13 14:56:52 VM-20-7-centos sudo[27219]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by root(uid=0)
Mar 13 14:56:52 VM-20-7-centos sudo[27219]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 13 14:57:01 VM-20-7-centos crond[27255]: PAM unable to dlopen(/usr/lib64/security/pam_access.so): /lib64/libnsl.so.1: symbol __nss_hash, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in f
Mar 13 14:57:01 VM-20-7-centos crond[27255]: PAM adding faulty module: /usr/lib64/security/pam_access.so
Mar 13 14:57:01 VM-20-7-centos crond[27255]: PAM unable to dlopen(/usr/lib64/security/pam_unix.so): /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /lib64/libcrypt.s
Mar 13 14:57:01 VM-20-7-centos crond[27255]: PAM adding faulty module: /usr/lib64/security/pam_unix.so
Mar 13 14:57:01 VM-20-7-centos crond[27255]: (root) PAM ERROR (Module is unknown)
Mar 13 14:57:01 VM-20-7-centos crond[27255]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Module is unknown)
Mar 13 14:57:04 VM-20-7-centos kernel: device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
Mar 13 14:57:05 VM-20-7-centos kernel: device eth0 left promiscuous mode
Mar 13 14:57:46 VM-20-7-centos sshd[27418]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=157.245.199.76  user=root
Mar 13 14:57:46 VM-20-7-centos sshd[27418]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
Mar 13 14:57:48 VM-20-7-centos sshd[27418]: Failed password for root from 157.245.199.76 port 42952 ssh2
Mar 13 14:57:48 VM-20-7-centos sshd[27418]: Connection closed by 157.245.199.76 port 42952 [preauth]
Mar 13 14:58:01 VM-20-7-centos crond[27491]: PAM unable to dlopen(/usr/lib64/security/pam_access.so): /lib64/libnsl.so.1: symbol __nss_hash, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in f
Mar 13 14:58:01 VM-20-7-centos crond[27491]: PAM adding faulty module: /usr/lib64/security/pam_access.so
Mar 13 14:58:01 VM-20-7-centos crond[27491]: PAM unable to dlopen(/usr/lib64/security/pam_unix.so): /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /lib64/libcrypt.s
Mar 13 14:58:01 VM-20-7-centos crond[27491]: PAM adding faulty module: /usr/lib64/security/pam_unix.so
Mar 13 14:58:01 VM-20-7-centos crond[27491]: (root) PAM ERROR (Module is unknown)
Mar 13 14:58:01 VM-20-7-centos crond[27491]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Module is unknown)
```

sudo systemctl start postgresql.service can be good

Comment: Look at the PostgreSQL log file. Try to start it with `pg_ctl` as user `postgres` (see the documentation) and look at the errors you get.